# Order Div on different rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, I have 6 Divs. In xs layout, it will be something like this:

Expected result in mobile screen (xs) size:
[image]

at other screen size, it would be like this:
Expected result in other screen size
[image]

I tried to use pull and push to order the Divs but did not get expected results.

My code is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 col-sm-push-10">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-pull-2">3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6 col-sm-pull-2">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-6">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the output put Divs into three rows.

Appreciated your help!

Thanks!

Comment: According to the bootstrap grid system, In a row max 12 cell grid max you can define. In your HTML that is more than that. Please read this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @jithuthomas, correct. That is how bootstrap handle rows. When you put more then 12 cells into a row, it will just put to next row. Check this out https://codepen.io/chrisoncode/pen/ihgLz

Comment: In this Codepen URL, all screen specifications did correctly like xs, s,md etc. but your col specification is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is correct only in xs, but not correct in sm and md. In sm, md and lg, I would only have two rows, the first row would be: 1      3      4  and second row is  2     5    6. With your code I got 1   2    3  for first row and 4   5    6 in second row in lg mode.

Comment: Can you clearly specify each size how you want to display, then I can help you correctly.

Comment: Sure, on original question, I attached two images, it shows as link, not it is not very clear. You could click the image link to see. For xs, three rows, for sm two rows. in xs, three rows are: 1  2 for row 1, 3, 4 for row 2 and 5, 6 for row 3. For sm, 1  3  4 for row 1 and 2 5 6 for row 2. Thanks!

Comment: Please find this link, created a sample code for you. https://codepen.io/Jithuthomas/pen/ZEboyJd

Comment: sorry I did not mention. The work was to clean an existing layout, which we have similar implementation as yours: have duplicated Divs in the layout. In real work, which Div is a complex widget, we would avoid duplication so it will reduce SQL and HTTP loading. I am looking for a solution without duplicated Divs. That is there are only 6 Divs for all screen sizes.